# NameError! I am following Django tutorial in part 5 when try to run test, getting error

Tags: python-3.x, linux, django-models, django-views, django-forms

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wDSL.png   NameError! I am following Django tutorial in part 5 when try to run test, getting error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have defined the function create_question above your test.  In the tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial05/), the function looks like:

```
def create_question(question_text, days):
    """
    Create a question with the given `question_text` and published the
    given number of `days` offset to now (negative for questions published
    in the past, positive for questions that have yet to be published).
    """
    time = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=days)
    return Question.objects.create(question_text=question_text, pub_date=time)
```

Comment: Yes, I defined but there is three classes and I have to define in every class?

Comment: No.  In the example you can see it's defined above the class.  You can call it from any class defined that same page, or, if you want it in other files as well, place it into its own file, eg, utils.py, and then include 'from utils import create_question' at the top of files where you want to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Finally error resolved.